# NGINX dns is not working on VPS

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, dns, centos

I'm a little new to VPS/Linux so please bear with me.

I have a domain name (attendahh.com) pointed to my host's nameservers.

I've set up /etc/nginx/conf.d/attendahh.com.conf as follows:

```
# the IP(s) on which your node server is running. I chose port 3000.
upstream attendahh.com {
    server 127.0.0.1:1999;
}

# the nginx server instance
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name attendahh.com attendahh;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/attendahh.log;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers and much $
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://attendahh.com/;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Then I `service nginx restart`.

I've read a bunch of tutorials and stack answers this is ostensibly all I need to do, but if I go to http://attendahh.com it does not work.

Things to note:

1. Going to my IP + port in the browser works just fine ( `23.226.227.16:1999` )
2. I have Cpanel for VPS installed (I tried to set up the DNS in there originally but it didn't work, I've since deleted the dns entry from there but it may still be affecting things)
3. Apache `virtual hosts` are commented out in `httpd.config`.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? Perhaps there's some conflict between `apache` and `nginx`?

Answer (score 1):

```
-       proxy_pass http://attendahh.com/;
+       proxy_pass http://attendahh.com;
```

Comment: If you read the answer below yours you'll see this didn't have any effect. Is it possible to remove Apache and Nginx and just start from scratch? Feel like there's something funky going on.

Comment: And how listen :80 port? Apache or nginx? `netstat -lnpt | grep 80`

Answer (score 0):

Nginx uses its own resolver, it doesn't use the system's resolver (/etc/resolver).

You have to configure it using the `resolver` directive. If you are not using the `resolver` directive, then use IP address in the `proxy_pass` directive.

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver

Comment: Can you give a code example of what I need to change here? The documentation doesn't really explain mucnh.

Comment: Have your reload your Nginx? And can the server connect to <IP>:<PORT>?

Comment: Yep, I've done `service nginx restart` and no luck. How do I check if the server can connect to <ip>:<port>?

Comment: Yep both Curl and WGET work fine. Is it possible that Apache is getting in the way?

Comment: Try changing it to `proxy_pass http://23.226.227.16:1999;`. Is the `Host` in `proxy_set_header` correct? What do you see when you said it does nothing? Check the access and error log too.

Comment: "It does nothing" as in I still get a 404 error when I go to the domain. The site is running on `Node/Express`, I don't know what the `host` in `proxy_set_header` should be...

Comment: Is there a way to check if NGINX is even handling my DNS?

Comment: If you are refering to attendahh.com domain, it is a new domain and the dns information hasn't propagated yet. If you do a `dig attendahh.com`, there isn't A record yet. The public won't be able to access it. So, either wait or set your host file manually for your own testing.

Comment: I set up the DNS 40 hours ago and it's currently pointing to an `nginx 502` page - http://attehdahh.com - so def my server...